# React & Redux CRUD: Displaying a single item not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, crud, mern

**EDIT:**

Tournament Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    tournaments: [],
    showTournament: "",
    loading: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_TOURNAMENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                tournaments: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case SHOW_TOURNAMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                // showTournament: state.tournaments.find(tournament => tournament._id === action.payload._id),
                showTournament: [action.payload, ...state.showTournament],
                loading: false
            };
```

Tournament Action:

```
export const showTournament = _id => dispatch => {
    dispatch(singleTourneyLoading());   
    axios
        .get(`/tournaments/${_id}`)
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type: SHOW_TOURNAMENT,
            payload: res.data
        }))
        .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};
```

ShowTournament component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TournamentRules from './rulesets';
import {
    showTournament,
    addParticipant,
    closeTournament,
    shuffleParticipants
} from '../../actions/tournamentActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { TournamentSignUp, StartTournament } from './buttons';
import { Button, Spinner } from 'reactstrap';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class TournamentShow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this);
        this.onStartTournament = this.onStartTournament.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            showTournament: "",
            redirectToStart: false
        };
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const _id = this.props.match.params.id;
        // Tried this, using props from state
        this.props.showTournament(_id);
        // Tried this, using local state
        const { tournaments } = this.props.tournament;
        const showTournament = tournaments.find(tournament => tournament._id === _id);
        this.setState({showTournament});
        console.log(
      this.props.tournament
    )
    };

    static propTypes = {
        tournament: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    onSignUp(tournamentId, user) {
        this.props.addParticipant(tournamentId, user);
    };

    onStartTournament(tourneyId, tourneyParticipants) {
        this.props.shuffleParticipants(tourneyId, tourneyParticipants);
        this.props.closeTournament(tourneyId);
        this.setState({
            redirectToStart: true
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { _id, title, type, hostedBy, schedule, status, participants } = this.state.showTournament;
        // const { _id, title, type, hostedBy, schedule, status, participants } = this.props.tournament.showTournament;
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;
        const redirectToStart = this.state.redirectToStart;
        if(!this.state.showTournament) {
            return <h1 style={{color: "lightgrey"}}>Tournament not found!</h1>
        };
        return (
            <div>
                { redirectToStart ? <Redirect to={`/tournaments/${_id}/start`} /> : null }
                { this.props.tournament.loading ?
                    <Spinner color="light" /> :
                    <div style={{color: "lightgrey"}}>
                        <h1 className="text-center">
                            { title }
                        </h1>
                        <h1 className="text-center" style={{fontSize:'1.2em'}}>Hosted by { hostedBy }</h1>
                        <hr style={{backgroundColor:"lightgrey"}} />
                        <h4>
                            Ruleset: { type }
                        </h4>
                        <h4>
                            <TournamentRules key={_id} type={ type } />
                        </h4>
                        <br/>
                        <h4>
                            Begins { moment(schedule).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }
                            <p>{ moment(schedule).format("h:mm a") }</p>
                        </h4>
                        <br />
                        <p className="text-center" style={{color: "#56A8CBFF", fontSize: "2em"}}>
                            ~ { status } for registration ~
                        </p>
                        <h4 className="text-left mt-5">
                            {
                                participants && participants.length === 1 ? 
                                `${participants && participants.length} Registered Fighter` : 
                                `${participants && participants.length} Registered Fighters`
                            }
                        </h4>
                        <ul>
                            {
                                participants && participants.map(participant => (
                                    <li key={participant._id} className="text-left" style={{fontSize: "1.1em"}}>{participant.username}</li>
                                ))
                            }
                        </ul>
                        {
                            isAuthenticated ?
                            <div>
                                <TournamentSignUp
                                    participants={participants}
                                    userId={user._id}
                                    onClick={() => this.onSignUp(_id, user)} 
                                />
                            </div> :
                            <Button block disabled>Log in to sign up for this tournament</Button>
                        }
                        {
                            isAuthenticated && user.username === hostedBy ?
                            <div>
                                <StartTournament
                                    participants={participants}
                                    onClick={() => this.onStartTournament(_id, participants)}
                                />
                            </div> :
                            null
                        }
                    </div>
                }
                <br /><Link to="/">Back to Tournaments main page</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tournament: state.tournament,
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, 
    { showTournament, addParticipant, closeTournament, shuffleParticipants }
)(TournamentShow);
```

BackEnd for Show One tournament

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Tournament.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(tournament => res.json(tournament))
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
});
```

The component renders the data ONLY if I access it via clicking the Link on the Show All page.  However that console.log in componentDidMount() shows me `showTournament: ""`

Which is odd because in my redux devtools, `showTournament:{}` is populated with the correct data.  It just doesn't persist, or maybe it isn't really there which is what the console log is showing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of app structure.  You have combined the actions for navigating to a page and loading data for a page such that you can’t do one without the other.  You need to separate data fetching from navigation.

If I were to enter a url with “/tournaments/5” directly into my browser. you need to be calling a dispatch action to fetch the data for tournament 5.

The way I usually set this up is that the individual tournament component has a selector that selects the data and an action to dispatch to fetch the data.  If the selector shows that the data hasn’t been loaded or requested, then I dispatch the action to fetch it.

Your navigation onClick handler should just handle navigating to the page, and the page should handle loading it’s own data.  That way the page will always have data whether it is navigated to, refreshed, or accessed directly.

**EDIT:**

The good news is that your routing is fine, mostly.  More specific paths need to go before broader ones, so `"/tournaments/:id/start"` needs to go before `"/tournaments/:id"` or else start pages will always match the main `/:id` path.

[I made a little demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-gagarin-4lf4x?file=/src/App.js) of the routing and it works. (but the back button is weird? I don't know if that's just a codesandbox issue)

When `Route` loads the component it passes in extra props.  You can use those props to get the id:

```
const _id = props.match.params.id;
```

So you can call the action to fetch data within `componentDidMount` (or `useEffect`) of your `TournamentShow` component.

**EDIT 2:**

When you are dealing with data that might or might not exist, you need to make sure that the object exists *before* you destructure it, or else you will get errors like `Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` because you are trying to access a property on `undefined` which is not an `object`.

One way to handle this is to exit the `render` function early when you are in the loading state:

```
    render() {

        const loading = this.props.tournament.loading || ! this.props.tournament.showTournament;

        if (loading) {
            return (
                <Spinner color="light" />
            )
        }

        const { _id, title, hostedBy, status, participants } = this.props.tournament.showTournament;

        return (
            <div>
               ....
```

The other way, which I think is the better way, is to separate the fetching, loading, and matching from the component display.  You would have a component `RenderTournament` which handles most of what's in your current component, but it requires a valid tournament prop.  Basically we only call this component once the data has loaded, and it shows the data. It no longer needs to be aware of `this.props.match` and no longer dispatches a fetch.  Let's make it so this component doesn't need to be connected to redux at all because we'll give it the actions as props.

You wrap this in an outer component which is the one that your `Route` directs to.  The outer component takes the `id` from `this.props.match.params` and handles the dispatch.  It connects to the redux store to get the tournament state and the actions to dispatch.

For the `render` of your outer component, you check whether the data is loaded and valid.  You either render a `Spinner` or you render your `RenderTournament` component will all of its props.

```
const RenderTournamentShow = ({
  tournament,
  auth,
  onSignUp,
  onStartTournament
}) => {
  const { _id, title, hostedBy, status, participants } = tournament;
  const { isAuthenticated, user } = auth;

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ color: "lightgrey" }}>
        <h1 className="text-center">
          {title}
          <span style={{ fontSize: "0.5em" }}> by {hostedBy}</span>
        </h1>

        <h3>
          <TournamentDescription key={_id} title={title} />
        </h3>

        <br />

        <p
          className="text-center"
          style={{ color: "#56A8CBFF", fontSize: "2em" }}
        >
          ~ {status} for registration ~
        </p>

        <h4 className="text-left mt-5">
          {participants && participants.length === 1
            ? `${participants && participants.length} Registered Fighter`
            : `${participants && participants.length} Registered Fighters`}
        </h4>

        <ul>
          {participants &&
            participants.map((participant) => (
              <li
                key={participant._id}
                className="text-left"
                style={{ fontSize: "1.1em" }}
              >
                {participant.username}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>

        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <div>
            <TournamentSignUp
              participants={participants}
              userId={user._id}
              onClick={() => onSignUp(_id, user)}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Button block disabled>
            Log in to sign up for this tournament
          </Button>
        )}

        {isAuthenticated && user.username === hostedBy ? (
          <div>
            <StartTournament
              participants={participants}
              onClick={() => onStartTournament(_id, participants)}
            />
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
      <br />
      <Link to="/">Back to Tournaments main page</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

class TournamentShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    this.props.showTournament(id);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    tournament: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  onSignUp(tournamentId, user) {
    this.props.addParticipant(tournamentId, user);
  }

  onStartTournament(tourneyId, tourneyParticipants) {
    this.props.updateTournamentStatus(tourneyId, tourneyParticipants);
  }

  render() {
    const loading =
      this.props.tournament.loading || !this.props.tournament.showTournament;

    if (loading) {
      return <Spinner color="light" />;
    } else {
      return (
        <RenderTournamentShow
          tournament={this.props.tournament.showTournament}
          auth={this.props.auth}
          onSignUp={this.props.addParticipant}
          onStartTournament={this.props.updateTournamentStatus}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  tournament: state.tournament,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  showTournament,
  addParticipant,
  updateTournamentStatus
})(TournamentShow);
```

Comment: I understand, I knew I wrote myself into a corner with that code.
Can you please, if you have a chance, provide a code snippet/example?

Comment: I edited my reply.  You don't need to rework the routing.  You just need to change where you fetch the data.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time out.  I'm gonna go through that and correct my code.  Thank you! I'll post again if I need clarification but hopefully I'll get this

Comment: I never solved this issue, and continued to build other parts of my app but this is coming back to haunt me.  I'm looking at the docs, and I followed your advice.  I gave the ShowPage's componentDidMount() the redux action for the GET tournament/:id but it's still not working

Comment: Can you post either your repo or a demo?

Comment: There is going to be a period of time while you're waiting to retrieve the data where you'll need to display some sort of loading state.  If you're trying to use the data before it has been loaded then you'll have problems.

Comment: I added a loading spinner also..
I tested it with console.log(state).  When I access the page, Redux state says `showTournament` is correct, and it renders properly.  But in the console log it shows showTournament is blank.  My repo:
https://github.com/CintBX/Smash-Hosting

Everything is in client/src, you'll see reducers, actions, components etc

Comment: The stuff in question is reducers/tournamentReducer, actions/tournamentActions, components/TournamentShow

Comment: Ugh I'm sorry I just realized, the repo isn't up to date cuz I've been working on a new branch. I'll update my post now

Comment: I'm looking through it now.  In `Show.js` you do check to see if it's loading, but only *after* you destructure properties from `this.props.tournament.showTournament`.  This is going to be a fatal error if `showTournament` is `undefined`.

Comment: Okay, this has gotten me one step closer.  I can refresh the page without the app breaking, but my showTournament is not persisting in the state past that initial render.  (Refreshing or accessing the URL just renders the spinner)
I'm still working at seeing what I did wrong on the redux(assuming that's it) side.. Thank you so much.   Of course if you have any other input feel free, but if not it's cool!

Comment: Fixed it, made a silly mistake in the reducer.  Will be sending you the Bounty points when it's available.  Thanks and take care Linda

Answer (score 1):

You button onClick is wrong

```
onClick={this.onShowTournament(_id)}
```

should be

```
onClick={() => this.onShowTournament(_id)}
```

About F5: it's normal that application loose their context.
You have two options:

1. code your id in route with query `?id=...` and look at that with something like [that](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-url-parameters-and-query-strings-with-react-router-fffdcea7a8e9)
2. with route params `<Route path="/:id" component={...} />` and (`useParams` or `withRouter`) from `react-router-dom`
3. persisted state (heavy operations and can make other mistakes)

PS look at [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org) or [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) for async actions in redux

Comment: Pardon me.. yeah.  My actual button onCLick is {this.onShowTournament.bind(this, _id)} because I didn't use a constructor in this component.  So it works without the arrow syntax.  I should probably refactor that

Comment: My fault... I did not understand the question to the end. Now I will dare to supplement my answer, if I understand what it is.

Comment: thanks for the update.  I'm going through that medium.com link you sent.  My app is already so.. .structured that I'm having a hard time incorporating this.  I'm still trying though.

I updated my post to include my current App.js file/routes for anyone who may see a simpler way to adjust it